# SSIS and Windows forms

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm fairly new to SSIS and would like some help.
I've got a SSIS package that has a number of data flow tasks. I want the user to be able to choose 
which task gets run. To enable this I created a form that the user can make their choices.
The form contains a combo box populated with a list of servers, a couple of radio buttons and a 
number of check boxes which relate to the DF tasks and any number can be selected.

What I need to know is how to pass the variables selected on the form to the ssis package.

Item Names are as follows:

- combo box - cbEnv
- Buttons - rbUnrec, rbRec
- Check boxes - cbAcc, cbAdd, cbBank, cbOrd

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could save the values to a db for SSIS to read.

Comment: It's a read only DB

Comment: Where have you created the form?  Is it in a separate app?

Comment: Created both the form and ssis in visual studio. I just need to pass the input from the form to the package

Comment: SSIS isn't designed to display a UI at runtime.  This is because its main purpose is to run scheduled, automated processes.  Instead, your UI could update a [configuration file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141682.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which your package will read when it next executes.

Comment: Can the form not pass the user input directly to the ssis package?

Comment: Sorry SSIS is designed to run without user input.  This prevents an automated job, running on a server without a monitor, from endless waiting for someone to click ok.  One of SSIS's main strengths is reading and writing data.  Output your settings to a text file and import them from within the package.  You can use [DTSExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to start the package running from within your form.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a go, thanks for your help

Comment: @user5367782 How are you planning to start the package execution?

Comment: you can declare a variable in the SSIS and then pass it to the package depending on how you are going to execute the package.  But as destination-data pointed out appropriately SSIS should run without user input.  Can your package really be 3 packages and depending on users choice a particular package is executed?  That way the packages stand on their own if you want to use for other automation events via sql agent etc.

Comment: @Tab Alleman - I was hoping to run the ssis package from a <continue> button on the form once the user had made their selections

Comment: @Matt - What do you mean by 3 packages

Comment: @user5367782 I get that, but I mean programmatically, what command / code to do you intend to use to start the package?

Comment: @Tab Alleman - Probably with DTEXEC

Comment: @user5367782  sorry I thought I had read 3 choices but the idea is to split up your package based on what task/data flow you would run per user choice and have X number of packages instead of one package then when the user makes their choice in your GUI you would execute a particular package not having to pass a parameter rather than executing an all inclusive package and passing a parameter. Two main benefits 1) SSIS part will be designed without relying on user input 2) the logic of what task to execute will be fully contained within your external program instead of split between both

Comment: @Matt - One of the problems is the number of DF tasks I've currently got is 45, I didn't really want to create a seperate package for each one, although there is merit in what you say about the logic been containe din the external program

Comment: I get what done is done at this point, I would offer for future separating them gives you flexibility to automate and run without being dependent on each other but you can still use shared connections, shared parameters etc. so that you don't have to redundantly develop other parts of the project...  anyway, how are you wanting to execute the packages command line with DTEXEC, via firing SQLAgent Jobs, tsql? if you update your question you will probably get more guidance from the community.

Comment: I'll need to think/work on that

Answer (score 0):

If you start the package with DTEXEC, you can pass parameters to the package with the /Parameter option.

This is fully described on the [MSDN page on DTEXEC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231187(v=sql.110).aspx).